# CSS Design with the Golden Ratio?

Tags: css

everybody is talking about the Golden Ratio, and about doing design including the thoughts about it. This is what I am trying to do now.
I want to put a CENTER Area and a SIDEBAR on my page in the golden ratio. But I am having the issue, not to know where to calculate element's margins and paddings in. How to set 'the perfect' margins and paddings (with respect to the Golden Ration)? Please Help me out with it.

Comment: I created a simple blog template with golden ratio typography. Please check it out https://github.com/VJAI/fibonacci

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some good resources for design and the 'Golden Ratio':

The good 'ole Phiculator!:

[http://www.thismanslife.co.uk/main.asp?contentid=phiculator](http://www.thismanslife.co.uk/phiculator)

An excellent article from a fave, NETTUTS called The Golden Ratio in Web Design:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-golden-ratio-in-web-design/

And, probably the one you're looking for, from Smashing Magazine (which you should dive into!), Applying Divine Proportion To Your Web Designs:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/29/applying-divine-proportion-to-web-design/